# dropping trailing '.0' from floats

Tags: python

I'm looking for a  way to convert numbers to string format, dropping any redundant '.0'

The input data is a mix of floats and strings. Desired output:

0   --> '0'

0.0 --> '0'

0.1 --> '0.1'

1.0 --> '1'

I've come up with the following generator expression, but I wonder if there's a faster way:

```
(str(i).rstrip('.0') if i else '0' for i in lst)
```

The truth check is there to prevent 0 from becoming an empty string.

EDIT: The more or less acceptable solution I have for now is this:

```
('%d'%i if i == int(i) else '%s'%i for i in lst)
```

It just seems strange that there is no elegant way to handle this (fairly straightforward) case in python.

Comment: `hash()` seems to be a little faster than `int()`, so you might use `hash(i)==i`, I'm not sure it's safe though

Comment: @ilius it's safe enough to guarantee a headache to anyone reading `hash` instead of `int`

Comment: And it's also completely wrong, `hash(2**64) == 8` for example

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2440786/908336

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(str(i)[-2:] == '.0' and str(i)[:-2] or str(i) for i in ...)
```

Answer (score 93):

See [PEP 3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/):

```
'g' - General format. This prints the number as a fixed-point
      number, unless the number is too large, in which case
      it switches to 'e' exponent notation.
```

Old style (not preferred):

```
>>> "%g" % float(10)
'10'
```

New style:

```
>>> '{0:g}'.format(float(21))
'21'
```

New style 3.6+:

```
>>> f'{float(21):g}'
'21'
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems like this does exactly what the OP wanted: elegantly strip superfluous trailing .0 off of integers but don't round, truncate or otherwise munge floating point numbers. And with a bonus of also automagically switching to exponent notation for large numbers!

Comment: @NoahSussman: '%g' may loose precision as shown in [dF's answer from 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/a/385392/4279).

Comment: This one doesn't work ```'{0:g}'.format(float(100000.5))
Out[7]: '100000'```

Answer (score 19):

`rstrip` doesn't do what you want it to do, it strips *any* of the characters you give it and not a suffix:

```
>>> '30000.0'.rstrip('.0')
'3'
```

Actually, just `'%g' % i`  will do what you want.
EDIT: as Robert pointed out in his comment this won't work for large numbers since it uses the default precision of %g which is 6 significant digits.

Since `str(i)` uses 12 significant digits, I think this will work:

```
>>> numbers = [ 0.0, 1.0, 0.1, 123456.7 ]
>>> ['%.12g' % n for n in numbers]
['1', '0', '0.1', '123456.7']
```

Comment: %g is not the right way to accomplish this: >>> "%g" % 123456.7 # => '123457'.

Comment: So I need to replace rstrip('.0') with rstrip('0').rstrip('.'), which I think will be very slow.

There are more pitfalls with the '%g' operator:

>>> "%.20g" % 123456.7 # ==>
'123456.69999999999709'

Comment: @Algorias: not really a pitfall, you're getting the value of the best representation of 123456.7 as a Python double. To get the same as str(x), use "%.12g".

Comment: last line of demo output should read ['0', '1', '0.1', '123456.7'] - can't edit because edits need to be 6 characters.

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> x = '1.0'
>>> int(float(x))
1
>>> x = 1
>>> int(float(x))
1
```

Comment: Not great: `x = 0.1` and `int(float(x))`. Result is `0`

Answer (score 9):

So much ugliness out there…

My personal favorite is to convert `float`s that don't require to be a `float` (= when they actually are integers) to `int`, thus removing the, now useless, trailing `0`

`(int(i) if i.is_integer() else i for i in lst)`

Then you can print them normally.

Answer (score 8):

```
def floatstrip(x):
    if x == int(x):
        return str(int(x))
    else:
        return str(x)
```

Be aware, though, that Python represents 0.1 as an imprecise float, on my system 0.10000000000000001 .

Comment: Thanks, I might end up using the int check, though i would have preferred avoiding it.

Answer (score 7):

To print a `float` that has an integer value as an `int`:

```
format = "%d" if f.is_integer() else "%s"
print(format % f)
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/eaUpLj)

```
             0.0 -> 0
             0.1 -> 0.1
            10.0 -> 10
      12345678.9 -> 12345678.9
     123456789.0 -> 123456789
12345678912345.0 -> 12345678912345
12345678912345.6 -> 1.23456789123e+13
  1.000000000001 -> 1.0
```

Answer (score 4):

If you only care about 1 decimal place of precision (as in your examples), you can just do:

```
("%.1f" % i).replace(".0", "")
```

This will convert the number to a string with 1 decimal place and then remove it if it is a zero:

```
>>> ("%.1f" % 0).replace(".0", "")
'0'
>>> ("%.1f" % 0.0).replace(".0", "")
'0'
>>> ("%.1f" % 0.1).replace(".0", "")
'0.1'
>>> ("%.1f" % 1.0).replace(".0", "")
'1'
>>> ("%.1f" % 3000.0).replace(".0", "")
'3000'
>>> ("%.1f" % 1.0000001).replace(".0", "")
'1'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from decimal import Decimal
'%g' % (Decimal(str(x)))
```

Comment: This will yield 123457 for 123456.7 which I don't think is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

Using Python's [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) (use [str.format()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) with Python 3.0):

```
from decimal import Decimal

def format_number(i):
    return '%g' % (Decimal(str(i)))
```

Comment: You would better use Decimal(str(i)), or you will end up with an exception if i is a float.

Comment: Old formatting (`%` formatting) works too in Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

Following code will convert contents of variable no as it is i.e. `45.60`. If you use `str` the output will be `45.6`

```
no = 45.60

strNo = "%.2f" %no
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str(x)[-2:] == '.0' and int(x) or x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> '%g' % 0
'0'
>>> '%g' % 0.0
'0'
>>> '%g' % 0.1
'0.1'
>>> '%g' % 1.0
'1'
```

Comment: >>> "%g" % 123456.7 # => '123457'.

Comment: >>> "%g" % 1234567.7 =>
'1.23457e+06'

Answer (score 0):

Us the 0 prcision and add a period if you want one.  EG "%.0f."

```
>>> print "%.0f."%1.0
1.
>>>
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP asked for: "%.0f." % 0.1 # => 0., instead of 0.1.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, with Jinja2 where var = 10.3

`{{ var|round|int }}` will emit integer `10`

`round(method='floor')` and `round(method='ceil')` are also available.

So that were var2 = 10.9
`{{ var|round(method='floor')|int }}` will still emit integer `10`

Precision can also be controlled using a keyword argument `precision=0` of the `round` function.

ref: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#round

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with a value from a json dictionary (returned by an API). All the above didnt help me so i constructed by own helper function. It truncates all the trailing zeros.

I Hope it helps someone out there

```
def remove_zeros(num):
    nums = list(num)
    indexes = (list(reversed(range(len(nums)))))
    for i in indexes:
        if nums[i] == '0':
            del nums[-1]
        else:
            break
    return "".join(nums)

num = "0.000000363000"
print(remove_zeros(num))
```

prints :

```
    0.000000363
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this for removing trailing nonsignificant digits past a certain precision.

```
c = lambda x: float(int(x * 100)/100.)
c(0.1234)
```

Comment: If you are defining a function (which you are), it's better to use a regular function, not a lambda. This improves the readability of code.