# In Perl, how can I limit the number of places after the decimal point but have no trailing zeroes?

Tags: perl, printf, decimal-point

This question is similar to ["dropping trailing ‘.0’ from floats"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385325/dropping-trailing-0-from-floats), but for Perl and with a maximum number of digits after the decimal.

I'm looking for a way to convert numbers to string format, dropping any redundant '0', including not just right after the decimal.  And still with a maximum number of digital, e.g. 3

The input data is floats. Desired output:

```
0         -> 0
0.1       -> 0.1
0.11      -> 0.11
0.111     -> 0.111
0.1111111 -> 0.111
```

Comment: Hey, great question, I've had this one on my mind many times!  Just a thought: accept a more community-approved answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use [Math::Round](http://search.cpan.org/~grommel/Math-Round-0.05/Round.pm) to do this:

```
$ perl -MMath::Round=nearest -e 'print nearest(.001, 0.1), "\n"'
0.1
$ perl -MMath::Round=nearest -e 'print nearest(.001, 0.11111), "\n"'
0.111
```

Comment: This solution only works for small numbers.  `print` drops the fractional part or switches to scientific notation altogether after 15 digits; `nearest` can amplify any error already present in the number (e.g. rounding `111111111129995.56` to `.001` with `nearest` produces `111111111129995.58`, whereas `sprintf("%.3f", 111111111129995.56)` correctly produces `111111111129995.56`.)

Answer (score 19):

Use the following directly:

```
my $s = sprintf('%.3f', $f);
$s =~ s/\.?0*$//;

print $s
```

...or define a subroutine to do it more generically:

```
sub fstr {
  my ($value,$precision) = @_;
  $precision ||= 3;
  my $s = sprintf("%.${precision}f", $value);
  $s =~ s/\.?0*$//;
  $s
}

print fstr(0) . "\n";
print fstr(1) . "\n";
print fstr(1.1) . "\n";
print fstr(1.12) . "\n";
print fstr(1.123) . "\n";
print fstr(1.12345) . "\n";
print fstr(1.12345, 2) . "\n";
print fstr(1.12345, 10) . "\n";
```

Prints:

```
0
1
1.1
1.12
1.123
1.123
1.12
1.12345
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sprintf` combined with `eval`.

```
my $num = eval sprintf('%.3f', $raw_num);
```

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

my @num_array = (
    0, 1, 1.0, 0.1, 0.10, 0.11, 0.111, 0.1110, 0.1111111
);


for my $raw_num (@num_array) {
    my $num = eval sprintf('%.3f', $raw_num);
    print $num . "\n";
}
```

outputs:

```
0
1
1
0.1
0.1
0.11
0.111
0.111
0.111
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the output your looking for:

```
sub dropTraillingZeros{
$_ = shift;
s/(\d*\.\d{3})(.*)/$1/;
s/(\d*\.\d)(00)/$1/;
s/(\d*\.\d{2})(0)/$1/;
print "$_\n";
}
dropTraillingZeros(0);
dropTraillingZeros(0.1);
dropTraillingZeros(0.11);
dropTraillingZeros(0.111);
dropTraillingZeros(0.11111111);
```