# Perl rounding error again

Tags: perl

The example to show the problem:

- having a number 105;
- divide with 1000 (result 0.105)
- rouded to 2 decimal places should be: 0.11

Now, several scripts - based on answers to another questions:

This is mostly recommented and mostly upvoted solution is using `printf`.

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
my $i = 105;
printf "%.2f\n", $i/1000;   #prints 0.10
```

but prints a wrong result. In the comment to
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1838885 @Sinan Unur says (6 times upvoted comment):

> Use sprintf("%.3f", $value) for mathematical purposes too.

but, it didn't works "sometimes"... like above.

The another recommented solution `Math::BigFloat`:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Math::BigFloat;
my $i = 105;

Math::BigFloat->precision(-2);
my $r = Math::BigFloat->new($i/1000);

say "$r";   #0.10 ;(
```

Wrong result too. Another recommened one `bignum`:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use bignum ( p => -2 );
my $i = 105;
my $r = $i/1000;
say "$r";   #0.10 ;(
```

wrong again. ;(

Now the working ones:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Math::Round;
my $i = 105;
say nearest(0.01, $i/1000); #GREAT prints 0.11 :)
```

good result `0.11`, however a comment here https://stackoverflow.com/a/571740
complains about it.

and finally another recommendation "by my own" function:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
my $i = 105;
my $f = $i/1000;

say myround($f,2);  # 0.11

sub myround {
    my($float, $prec) = @_;
    my $f = $float * (10**$prec);
    my $r = int($f + $f/abs($f*2));
    return $r/(10**$prec);
}
```

prints `0.11` too, but can't prove it's correctness.

For the reference I was read:

- [How do you round a floating point number in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/178539)
- [In Perl, how can I limit the number of places after the decimal point but have no trailing zeroes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/571329)
- [How do I set the floating point precision in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1838808)
- and many-many others...
- and finally this too:
  http://www.exploringbinary.com/inconsistent-rounding-of-printed-floating-point-numbers/
  what gives a an **really good** overall view to the problem.

I understand than it is common problem to all languages, but please, after all
above reading - I still have this question:

What is the **error-proof** way in perl to round a floating point number to N
decimal places - with mathematically correct way, e.g. what will round results
like `105/1000` correctly to N decimal places without "surprises"...

Comment: Personally I would always rely on database like Pg/Oracle for this type of calculation.

Comment: I should point out that in your Math::Bigfloat solution you passed a common floating point number into the new(), meaning that it was too late to solve your problem.  You should probably make a Bigfloat out of a (pre-division) integer so as to allow Bigfloat's division method to give you something that you can work with.

Comment: +1 for tjd's comment. I would have thought (happy to be proven wrong) that if you use Math::Bigfloat correctly, it will be error-proof

Comment: There is no error proof way to do anything at all with fp numbers, except to store numbers that can be represented by n/2^m, or perform calculations on those numbers where the internal state is always representable by n/2^m, as well as the result.  Otherwise, error is inherent in the storage format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the old Integer math days of programming, we use to *pretend* to use decimal places:

```
N = 345
DISPLAY N        # Displays 345
DISPLAY (1.2) N  # Displays 3.45
```

We learned a valuable trick when attempting to round sales taxes correctly:

```
my $amount = 1.344;
my $amount_rounded = sprintf "%.2f", $amount + .005;
my $amount2 = 1.345;
my $amount_rounded2 = sprintf "%.2f", $amount2 + .005;
say "$amount_rounted   $amount_rounded2";  # prints 1.34 and 1.35
```

By adding in 1/2 of the precision, I display the rounding correctly. When the number is 1.344, adding .005 made it 1.349, and chopping off the last digit displays dip lays 1.344. When I do the same thing with 1.345, adding in .005 makes it 1.350 and removing the last digit displays it as 1.35.

You could do this with a subroutine that will return the *rounded* amount.

---

### Interesting...

There is a [PerlFAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#Does-Perl-have-a-round()-function%3f-What-about-ceil()-and-floor()%3f-Trig-functions%3f) on this subject. It recommends simply using `printf` to get the correct results:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my $number = .105;
say "$number";
printf "%.2f\n", $number;   # Prints .10 which is incorrect
printf "%.2f\n", 3.1459;    # Prins 3.15 which is correct
```

For *Pi*, this works, but not for `.105`. However:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my $number = .1051;
say "$number";
printf "%.2f\n", $number;   # Prints .11 which is correct
printf "%.2f\n", 3.1459;    # Prints 3.15 which is correct
```

This looks like an issue with the way Perl stores .105 internally. Probably something like `.10499999999` which would be correctly rounded downwards. I also noticed that Perl warns me about using `round` and `rounding` as possible future reserved words.

Comment: The FAQ says you can use `sprintf` to fix the error, but the OP is using `sprintf` to round without first fixing the error.

Comment: I didn't see anything in the FAQ about having to _fix the error_. The FAQ says to use `printf` and `sprintf` for rounding. Perl displays the number as `.105`, but then `sprintf` doesn't round what is displayed, but `.104999...` instead.

Comment: (That's not pi. 3.14159...)

Comment: I just took your word for it. Allow me to rephrase: You say the FAQ says you can use sprintf to fix the error, but the OP is using sprintf to round without first fixing the error.

Comment: The FAQ exactly says: _For rounding to a certain number of digits, sprintf() or printf() is usually the easiest route._ . Because (IMHO) all users want get _correct_ result, this is a bad advice in a FAQ. The only solution is using own rounding function, as the FAQ says later: _In these cases, it probably pays not to trust whichever system of rounding is being used by Perl, but instead to implement the rounding function you need yourself._ So, (unfortunately) the sprintf advice is bad (IMHO).

Comment: This solution simply displaces where the error occurs rather than addressing it.

Answer (score 11):

You're expecting a specific behaviour when the number is exactly `0.105`, but floating point errors mean you can't expect a number to be exactly what you think it is.

105/1000 is a periodic number in binary just like 1/3 is periodic in decimal.

```
105/1000
       ____________________
= 0.00011010111000010100011 (bin)

~ 0.00011010111000010100011110101110000101000111101011100001 (bin)

= 0.10499999999999999611421941381195210851728916168212890625
```

0.1049999... is less than 0.105, so it rounds to 0.10.

But even if you had 0.105 exactly, that would still round to 0.10 since `sprintf` rounds half to even. A better test is 155/1000

```
155/1000
       ____________________
= 0.00100111101011100001010 (bin)

~ 0.0010011110101110000101000111101011100001010001111010111 (bin)

= 0.1549999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875
```

0.155 should round to 0.16, but it rounds to 0.15 due to floating point error.

```
$ perl -E'$_ = 155; say sprintf("%.2f", $_/1000);'
0.15

$ perl -E'$_ = 155; say sprintf("%.0f", $_/10)/100;'
0.16
```

The second one works because 5/10 isn't periodic, and therein lies the solution. As Sinan Unur said, you can correct the error by using `sprintf`. But you have to round to an integer if you don't want to lose your work.

```
$ perl -E'
   $_ = 155/1000;

   $_ *= 1000;                # Move decimal point past significant.
   $_ = sprintf("%.0f", $_);  # Fix floating-point error.
   $_ /= 10;                  # 5/10 is not periodic
   $_ = sprintf("%.0f", $_);  # Do our rounding.
   $_ /= 100;                 # Restore decimal point.

   say;
'
0.16
```

That will fix the rounding error, allowing `sprintf` to properly round half to even.

```
0.105  =>  0.10
0.115  =>  0.12
0.125  =>  0.12
0.135  =>  0.14
0.145  =>  0.14
0.155  =>  0.16
0.165  =>  0.16
```

If you want to round half up instead, you'll need to using something other than `sprintf` to do the final rounding. Or you could add `s/5\z/6/;` before the division by 10.

---

But that's complicated.

The first sentence of the answer is key. You're expecting a specific behaviour when the number is exactly `0.105`, but floating point errors mean you can't expect a number to be exactly what you think it is. The solution is to introduce a tolerance. That's what rounding using `sprintf` does, but it's a blunt tool.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use POSIX qw( ceil floor );

sub round_half_up {
   my ($num, $places, $tol) = @_;

   my $mul = 1; $mul *= 10 for 1..$places;
   my $sign = $num >= 0 ? +1 : -1;

   my $scaled = $num * $sign * $mul;
   my $frac = $scaled - int($scaled);

   if ($sign >= 0) {
      if ($frac < 0.5-$tol) {
         return floor($scaled) / $mul;
      } else {
         return ceil($scaled) / $mul;
      }
   } else {
      if ($frac < 0.5+$tol) {
         return -floor($scaled) / $mul;
      } else {
         return -ceil($scaled) / $mul;
      }
   }
}
```

```
say sprintf '%5.2f', round_half_up( 0.10510000, 2, 0.00001);  #  0.11
say sprintf '%5.2f', round_half_up( 0.10500001, 2, 0.00001);  #  0.11  Within tol
say sprintf '%5.2f', round_half_up( 0.10500000, 2, 0.00001);  #  0.11  Within tol
say sprintf '%5.2f', round_half_up( 0.10499999, 2, 0.00001);  #  0.11  Within tol
say sprintf '%5.2f', round_half_up( 0.10410000, 2, 0.00001);  #  0.10
say sprintf '%5.2f', round_half_up(-0.10410000, 2, 0.00001);  # -0.10
say sprintf '%5.2f', round_half_up(-0.10499999, 2, 0.00001);  # -0.10  Within tol
say sprintf '%5.2f', round_half_up(-0.10500000, 2, 0.00001);  # -0.10  Within tol
say sprintf '%5.2f', round_half_up(-0.10500001, 2, 0.00001);  # -0.10  Within tol
say sprintf '%5.2f', round_half_up(-0.10510000, 2, 0.00001);  # -0.11
```

There's probably existing solutions that work along the same lines.

Comment: HUH! ;) Really detailed answer. Thank you. So, in the result: **a.)**  Can't rely on the `printf`/`sprintf`, because it is not doing correct rounding after the decimal point **b.)** should use everytime such above `round_half_up` function to get the correct result.

Comment: @kobame I think your **a.** is incorrect.  `printf`/`sprintf` will do the right thing with what you give it.  Not understanding the limitations of binary floating point numbers can lead a programmer to overestimate the accuracy of what they are feeding to `printf`/`sprintf`

Comment: @tjd, "`printf`/`sprintf` will do the right thing with what you give it.", What are you talking about? He specifically asked to replace `printf "%.2f\n", $i/1000` because it doesn't do what he wants.

Comment: @ikegami, I thought I was supporting your point that `printf` will behave as expected when handed `0.10499999999999999611421941381195210851728916168212890625`.  Am I incorrect?

Comment: @tjd Sorry, an normal (or call them oridinary/common/stupid) people for the `printf "%.2f", 155/1000` really want to get `0.16` and not `0.15`. Sry. Please understand and accept the fact, than not everybody who making some simple scripts in perl is an computer-expert who know in the details how are floating point numbers are stored. Ikegami's answer is GREAT because explained many things, but that doesn't change the fact = _can't rely on printf_ (because sometimes give a wrong result). The link on my question is has a great comparison, this is not only perl's problem. ;)

Comment: Do you expect `printf "%.2f", 154.99999999/1000` to be `0.16`? The point tjd is making is that there is no difference between `154.99999999/1000` and `155/1000`, so you'll inevitably get it wrong it if you expect to be able to compare if a value is exactly `155/1000` or greater.

Comment: @ikegami - See, i know than mathematically `0.999999(periodically)` is EXACTLY `== 1` !!! Now understand than I need to use my own rounding function to get correct result. Thats ok for me - and thanx. :)

Comment: `154.99999999/1000` is not periodic. Pretend I said `154.99999993/1000`

Answer (score 3):

Your custom function should mostly work as expected.  Here's how it works and how you can verify it's correct:

```
sub myround {
    my($float, $prec) = @_;

    # Prevent div-by-zero later on
    if ($float == 0) { return 0; }

    # Moves the decimal $prec places to the right
    # Example: $float = 1.234, $prec = 2
    #   $f = $float * 10^2;
    #   $f = $float * 100;
    #   $f = 123.4;
    my $f = $float * (10**$prec);

    # Round 0.5 away from zero using $f/abs($f*2)
    #   if $f is positive, "$f/abs($f*2)" becomes  0.5
    #   if $f is negative, "$f/abs($f*2)" becomes -0.5
    #   if $f is zero, we have a problem (hence the earlier if statement)
    # In our example:
    #   $f = 123.4 + (123.4 / (123.4 * 2));
    #   $f = 123.4 + (0.5);
    #   $f = 123.9;
    # Then we truncate to integer:
    #   $r = int(123.9);
    #   $f = 123;
    my $r = int($f + $f/abs($f*2));

    # Lastly, we shift the deciaml back to where it should be:
    #   $r / 10^2
    #   $r / 100
    #   123 / 100
    #   return 1.23;
    return $r/(10**$prec);
}
```

However, the following it will throw an error for `$float = 0`, so there's an additional `if` statement at the beginning.

The nice thing about the above function is that it's possible to round to *negative* decimal places, allowing you round to the left of the decimal.  For example, `myround(123, -2)` will give `100`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd add [`use bignum`](http://perldoc.perl.org/bignum.html) to your original code example.

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use bignum;

my $i = 105;                # Parsed as Math::BigInt
my $r = $i / 1000;          # Overloaded division produces Math::BigFloat
say $r->ffround(-2, +inf);  # Avoid using printf and the resulting downgrade to common float.
```

This solves the error you made in your `use Math::BigFloat` example by parsing your numbers into objects imediately and not waiting for you to pass the results of a round off error into `Math::BigFloat->new`

Comment: I'm probably missed something from your answer, because this script prints for me `0.10` too, and not the correct `0.11`.

Comment: @kobame, you were right.  I made the mistake of allowing printf to downgrade the object to a common float.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, Perl printf/sprintf uses wrong algorithm. I made this conclusion considering at least the following simple example:

```
# The same floating part for both numbers (*.8830 or *.8829) is expected in the rounded value, but it is different for some reason:
printf("%.4f\n", "7.88295"); # gives 7.8830
printf("%.4f\n", "8.88295"); # gives 8.8829
```

The integer part should not have any influence in this example, but it has.
I got this result with Perl 5.8.8.