# Why does sprintf round the fractional part of 5.555 and 0.555 differently?

Tags: perl, floating-point, printf, rounding

Can someone explain why there is a difference in behavior here?

```
perl -E 'say sprintf("%.2f",5.555);'
5.55    

perl -E 'say sprintf("%.2f",0.555);'
0.56
```

I have read that `sprintf()` rounds up if the following digits is 5 or greater. So why doesn't it round up to 0.56 in the second case?

Comment: Very good answers are here http://stackoverflow.com/q/24493228/632407

Comment: On a related note, `sprintf` rounds to even, so `sprintf '%.0f', 0.5` gives `0` and `sprintf '%.0f', 1.5` gives `2` even though `0.5` and `1.5` can be represented exactly as a floating point number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The closest IEEE 754 64-bit binary floating point number to 0.555 is 0.55500000000000004884981308350688777863979339599609375. It is very slightly closer to 0.56 than to 0.55.

The closest IEEE 754 64-bit binary floating point number to 5.555 is 5.55499999999999971578290569595992565155029296875. It is very slightly closer to 5.55 than to 5.56.

In each case, the output is the nearest decimal with 2 decimal places to the actual value of the internal number.

As Pascal Cuoq says in a comment, 0.555 is in the [binade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binade) [0.5 … 1), in which representable floating-point numbers are separated by 2<sup>-53</sup>. By contrast, 5.555 is in the binade [4 … 8), in which representable floating-point numbers are separated by 2<sup>-50</sup>. That is why the fractional parts are different for 0.555 and 5.555.

Comment: +1.How did you know about this representation?

Comment: @Jim I used Java: `System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.555));`, but there are many ways of doing it, including web sites.

Comment: I don't understand what this ` 0.555 is in the binade [0.5 … 1),` means. Can you please explain it to me?

Comment: @Jim See [binade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binade). It is just a range of numbers with the same exponent in IEEE floating point.

Comment: I have rolled back the latest edit because code tags were added to simple numbers and ranges that I meant in their mathematical sense, not as quotes from code.

Answer (score 5):

Because printf rounds the value, just try:

```
perl -e 'printf("%.25f", 5.555)'
```

gives:

```
5.5549999999999997157829057
```

rounded to `5.55` with `printf('%.2f', 5.55)`

and

```
perl -e 'printf("%.25f", 0.555)'
```

gives

```
0.5550000000000000488498131
```

rounded to `0.56` with `printf('%.2f', 0.55)`

Comment: Why did you do .25f? How did you choose this 25?

Comment: @Jim: It's just an example to be sure to have a lot of decimal, you could do the same with `%.10`

Comment: +1.So basically the idea was to use a big formatter so that the number expands to see the actual representation?

Answer (score 1):

If you want more consistent results, check [`Math::Round`](http://search.cpan.org/~grommel/Math-Round-0.06/Round.pm)

```
perl -MMath::Round=:all -E 'say nearest(.01, 0.555)'
0.56
```

---

```
perl -MMath::Round=:all -E 'say nearest(.01, 5.555)'
5.56
```

Comment: Is this library active?It was created in 2000.Sorry but due to my background I don't know how the perl libraries are maintained/supported

Comment: @Jim it was updated after that http://search.cpan.org/~grommel/Math-Round-0.06/

Comment: Even the update is in 2006.How can one know if it is actively used by many users?

Comment: It's being used by [these other modules](https://metacpan.org/requires/distribution/Math-Round?sort=[[2,1]]).

Comment: @Jim Just because a module hasn't been updated in a while doesn't mean that it's not maintained. Often it means that the module Just Works and hasn't needed any updates. When you're not sure, also look at the [CPAN Testers results](http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/M/Math-Round.html?oncpan=1&distmat=1&version=0.06) for the module (in this case, 7315 passes and 1 failure) and the [active bug reports](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Math-Round). Both of these are available from the sidebar if you look at the documentation on [metacpan](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Round).

Comment: @mpapec:I assume that the `.01` argument is to denote that we want decimal?What other alternatives could there have been?