# convert float64 to int (excel to pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have imported excel file into python pandas. but when I display customer numbers I get in float64 format i.e

> 7.500505e+09 , 7.503004e+09
>   how do convert the column containing these numbers

Comment: `df['col'] = df['col'].astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

int(yourVariable) will cast your float64 to a integer number.
Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @rahuldbz no ­­

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas DataFrames `style.format` function to apply a formatting to a column like in **https://towardsdatascience.com/style-pandas-dataframe-like-a-master-6b02bf6468b0**. If you want to round the numbers to i.e. 2 decimal places follow the accepted answer in [Python float to Decimal conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316238/python-float-to-decimal-conversion). Conversion to an `int` reduces accuracy a bit too much i think

For the conecpt binary floats in general (what `float64` is) see [Python - round a float to 2 digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24634664/python-round-a-float-to-2-digits)

Answer (score 0):

Please use pd.set_option to control the precision's to be viewed

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> a = pd.DataFrame({'sam':[7.500505e+09]})
>>> pd.set_option('float_format', '{:f}'.format)
>>> a
                sam
0 7500505000.000000
>>>
```

Comment: i want it in 'int'

Comment: this didnt work . it converted all those into float nd later i converted it into integer