# How to round to zero decimals if there is no decimal value with Jinja2?

Tags: python, templates, flask, rounding, jinja2

I building a website using the (excellent) [Flask framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/) in which I now want to display some numbers. The [round filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#round) provided by jinja2 works fine, except for when there is no decimal value:

```
{{ 1.55555|round(2) }} -> 1.56
{{ 1.5|round(2) }} -> 1.5
{{ 1.0|round(2) }} -> 1.0
{{ 1|round(2) }} -> 1.0
```

But I want the last two to be displayed like `1` (without a trailing `.0`). Does anybody know how I can do this with jinja2? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]

I tried using [trim()](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#trim), but to my surprise the snippet below gives a `TypeError: do_trim() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`:

```
{{ 1.0|round(2)|trim('.0') }}
```

Comment: I don't think you can with default Jinja2 filters. Do it in Python with [Formatting floats in Python without superfluous zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2440692) perhaps, or create your own filter that implements that.

Comment: `trim` expects only the value to trim as argument. You cannot specify WHAT to trim out.

Comment: Warning! "|trim('.0')" turns 10.0 into 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`string` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#string), then use [`str.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip):

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> print(jinja2.Template('''
... {{ (1.55555|round(2)|string).rstrip('.0') }}
... {{ (1.5|round(2)|string).rstrip('.0') }}
... {{ (1.0|round(2)|string).rstrip('.0') }}
... {{ (1|round(2)|string).rstrip('.0') }}
... ''').render())

1.56
1.5
1
1
```

---

**NOTE**

Using `str.rstrip`, you will get an empty string for `0`.

```
>>> jinja2.Template('''{{ (0|round(2)|string()).strip('.0') }}''').render()
u''
```

Here's a solution to avoid above (call `rstrip` twice; once with `0`, once with `.`)

```
>>> print(jinja2.Template('''
... {{ (1.55555|round(2)|string).rstrip('0').rstrip('.') }}
... {{ (1.5|round(2)|string).rstrip('0').rstrip('.') }}
... {{ (1.0|round(2)|string).rstrip('0').rstrip('.') }}
... {{ (1|round(2)|string).rstrip('0').rstrip('.') }}
... {{ (0|round(2)|string).rstrip('0').rstrip('.') }}
... ''').render())

1.56
1.5
1
1
0
```

**UPDATE** Above codes will trim `10` to `1`. Following code does not have the issue. using [`format` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#format).

```
>>> print(jinja2.Template('''
... {{ ("%.2f"|format(1.55555)).rstrip('0').rstrip('.') }}
... {{ ("%.2f"|format(1.5)).rstrip('0').rstrip('.') }}
... {{ ("%.2f"|format(1.5)).rstrip('0').rstrip('.') }}
... {{ ("%.2f"|format(1.0)).rstrip('0').rstrip('.') }}
... {{ ("%.2f"|format(0)).rstrip('0').rstrip('.') }}
... {{ ("%.2f"|format(10)).rstrip('0').rstrip('.') }}
... ''').render())

1.56
1.5
1.5
1
0
10
```

Comment: That is awesome! Works like a charm! It would be even more awesome if you also have a solution for the empty string issue.. :)

Comment: This trims `10` to `1`.

Comment: @kennysong, Thank you for the comment. I added another solution without the issue you mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

If you're going to use this a lot, I think it's best to write a custom filter to avoid clutter, like this:

```
from jinja2 import filters

def myround(*args, **kw):
    # Use the original round filter, to deal with the extra arguments
    res = filters.do_round(*args, **kw)
    # Test if the result is equivalent to an integer and
    # return depending on it
    ires = int(res)
    return (res if res != ires else ires)
```

Register it, and you're done. Example in the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> from jinja2 import Environment
>>> env = Environment()
>>> env.filters['myround'] = myround
>>> env.from_string("{{ 1.4|myround(2) }}").render()
u'1.4'
>>> env.from_string("{{ 1.4|myround }}").render()
u'1'
>>> env.from_string("{{ 0.3|myround }}").render()
u'0'
```

Answer (score 2):

A better solution, **to avoid 60.0 becoming 6 and 0.0 becoming empty**,

instead of:

```
(( YOURNUMBER )|string).rstrip('0')
```

do this:

```
(( YOURNUMBER )|string )[:-2]
```

This will cut off the last 2 characters of the string. Since round(0) always produces a number that will have a .0 at the end, this will solve the problem nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do

```
{{ ((1|round(2))|string).split('.')[0] }}
```

Process breakdown:

1. `1|round(2)` -> `1.0`
2. `|string` will convert the output to string so that we can use `split()`
3. `.split('.')` will split the string with `.` delimiter -> `["1", "0"]`
4. As `.split()` returns an array, `[0]` after it will get the string at 0th postition -> "1"
5. [optional] If you want data type of result to be number then do `|int` at the end