# Work out significant decimal points to format floating point number

Tags: python, floating-point, precision

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658763/how-do-i-suppress-scientific-notation-in-python) which covers how to suppress scientific notation, but I'd like to go a step further and also work out the formatting string (i.e. the number of required decimal points to represent a number).

My idea so far is to assume a very high resolution (20 in this example) and reduce trailing zeroes as suggested in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440692/formatting-floats-in-python-without-superfluous-zeros). Is there perhaps a *better* way to achieve this?

```
>>> f = 0.00000008
>>> s = '{:.20f}'.format(f)
>>> s
'0.00000008000000000000'
>>> s.rstrip('0')
'0.00000008'
```

Note, I don't want scientific notation either (which you would get with a formatting string of `{:g}`).

Comment: What would you do if the excess digits are *not* zero?  Like `1/3.0`?

Comment: Good question. Perhaps display up to a maximum number of decimal points.

Answer (score 0):

The max number of significant digits in a float is [15](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.float_info) (the power is separate from this). So there's no point in accounting for more digits past that, as they wouldn't be right. Knowing what the power of ten for a given number will tell you how many zeros to pad out in the front.

If what you're formatting will never get above one, then the following will suffice:

```
from math import log10

def floatformat(f):
    pwr = log10(f)
    return '{:.0{}f}'.format(f, int(abs(pwr)) + 15).rstrip('0')
```

But if you're parsing any possible float value, you'll have to handle large numbers a bit differently to get trailing zeros and not random inaccurate digits.

```
def floatformat(f):
    sigs = 15  # number of accurate digits that a float can contain
    pwr = log10(f)

    if pwr > sigs:  # power above accurate digits
         s = '{:.{}f}'.format(f / 10 ** int(pwr), sigs)
         s = s.replace('.', '')  # remove decimal point, no longer necessary here
         s = s + '0' * (int(pwr) - sigs)  # add in trailing zeros

    elif 0 < pwr <= sigs:  # power within accurate digits
        s = '{:.{}f}'.format(f, sigs - int(pwr)).rstrip('0')

    else:  # power below accurate digits
        s = '{:.0{}f}'.format(f, int(abs(pwr)) + sigs).rstrip('0')

    if s[-1] == '.': s = s[:-1]  # remove trailing decimal point if needed
    return s
```

All this is doing is keeping the accurate digits, then shuffling them around to have the correct power without the scientific notation.

Examples:

```
>>> floatformat(0.00000008)
'0.00000008'
>>> floatformat(0.0000000000000000000000000000008)
'0.0000000000000000000000000000008'
>>> floatformat(0.00000000000000000000000000000080067)
'0.00000000000000000000000000000080067'
>>> floatformat(2.31451103e7)
'23145110.3'
>>> floatformat(2.31451103e3)
'2314.51103'
>>> 935.16087e203 == float(floatformat(935.16087e203))  # conversion check to see if power is handled correctly
True
>>> import sys
>>> floatformat(sys.float_info.max)
'179769313486231600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
>>> floatformat(sys.float_info.min)
'0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022250738585072'
```