# Python float formatting with no exponent and max precision not fixed precision

Tags: python, floating-point, formatting

I have a long list of floating point numbers to be formatted as follows:

Examples:

case 1) `6.0 -> 6.0` (No trailing zeros)

case 2) `1.23456789 -> 1.234567` (or `1.234568`) (Max precision of 6)

case 3) `0.000004 -> 0.000004` (No exponent)

I can use

```
'{}'.format(round(x, 6))
```

for cases 1 & 2 but 3 gives 4e-06

If I use

```
'{:6f}'.format(6.0)
```

I get 6.000000 for case 1)

Is there a clean way to get the formatting I want?

Comment: Well, considering you want two different formats, you'll need two different format strings.

Comment: I don't want two different formats, just no trailing zeros, no exponent and max precision of 6

Comment: Yes (as NAmorim posted earlier)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perhaps you can consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440692/formatting-floats-in-python-without-superfluous-zeros) solution.

Your case:

```
print ('%.6f' % data).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
```

Comment: I just knew it would have been asked before (or similar). This works.

Answer (score -1):

Use `%.6f%(data)`

Hope it works !