# Python decimal formatting results inconsistent

Tags: python-3.x, format, decimal

Problem is to find the equation of a circle given three points. Got the math part down, but I'm having trouble getting the answer in the right format:

(x-Cx)^2+(y-Cy)^2=r^2

Specs say two digits after the decimal, but drop trailing 0s and decimals when appropriate. Here's the string I'm returning:

```
"(x-{0:.3g})^2+(y-{1:.3g})^2={2:.3g}^2".format(Cx, Cy, r)"
```

Here is an example:

Cx: 6.0000000000000000002
Cy: 5.74999999...
r: 3.25

Result: "(x-6.00)^2+(y-5.75)^2=3.25^2"

Expecting: "(x-6)^2+(y-5.75)^2=3.25^2"

Edit: [The code in question](https://github.com/stockdoodle/crashCourse/blob/master/dataVisualization/checkio.py)

Comment: switch to Python 3? Also if it actually is Python 2.X you are using, tag it please.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440692/formatting-floats-in-python-without-superfluous-zeros

Comment: Python3. Updated tag.

Comment: This works for me in python 2.7 as well. Just use `"%.2g" % Cx` notation instead of `.format`.

Comment: Does this just boil down to `"{:.3g}".format(6.0000000000000000002)`? That prints `6` for me.