# Can Decimal('5E+1') be simply converted to Decimal('50') in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, decimal, exponent, scientific-notation

#### Context

We display percentage values to agents in our app without trailing zeros (`50%` is much easier to quickly scan than is `50.000%`), and hitherto we've just used `quantize` to sort of brute force normalize the value to remove trailing zeros.

This morning I decided to look into using [`Decimal.normalize`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.normalize) instead, but ran into this:

Given the decimal value:

```
>>> value = Decimal('50.000')
```

Normalizing that value:

```
>>> value = value.normalize()
```

Results in:

```
>>> value
Decimal('5E+1')
```

I understand the value is the same:

```
>>> Decimal('5E+1') == Decimal('50')
True
```

But from a non-technical user's perspective, `5E+1` is basically meaningless.

#### Question

Is there a way to convert `Decimal('5E+1')` to `Decimal('50')`?

#### Note

I'm not looking to do anything that would change the value of the `Decimal` (e.g., removing decimal places altogether), since the value could be e.g., `Decimal('33.333')`. IOW, don't confuse my `50.000` example as meaning that we're only dealing with whole numbers.

Comment: There is no conversion here, the 2 values are exactly the same to Python, so you are asking for how to do formatting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the purposes of output formatting, you can print your normalized Decimal objects with the `f` format specifier. (While the format string docs say this defaults to a precision of 6, this does not appear to be the case for Decimal objects.)

```
>>> print('{:f}%'.format(decimal.Decimal('50.000').normalize()))
50%
>>> print('{:f}%'.format(decimal.Decimal('50.003').normalize()))
50.003%
>>> print('{:f}%'.format(decimal.Decimal('1.23456789').normalize()))
1.23456789%
```

If for some reason, you really want to make a new Decimal object with different precision, you can do that by just calling `Decimal` on the `f` format output, but it sounds like you're dealing with an output format problem, not something you should change the internal representation for.

```
>>> Decimal('{:f}'.format(Decimal('5E+1')))
Decimal('50')
>>> 
>>> Decimal('{:f}'.format(Decimal('50.000').normalize()))
Decimal('50')
>>> Decimal('{:f}'.format(Decimal('50.003').normalize()))
Decimal('50.003')
>>> Decimal('{:f}'.format(Decimal('1.23456789').normalize()))
Decimal('1.23456789')
```

Comment: In all seriousness, did you read the question? I’m not looking to format the output. I’m looking to change the decimal itself. I feel like stack overflow has lost its usefulness, and this is the reason; nobody even bothers to read the questions anymore.

Comment: @orokusaki: I did read the question, and your question says that the purpose of doing this is because `5E+1` is meaningless to nontechnical users. If nontechnical users are *seeing* `5E+1`, that's a problem of output formatting, not internal representation; you shouldn't be changing the Decimal object itself for that.

Comment: It doesn’t really matter what the purposes. What matters is that I asked a very specific questions and specified every detail about what I needed. If the answer is “you can’t do that”, that’s perfectly fine. But this business of everybody assuming that everybody else is an idiot and doesn’t know what they need is what ruined stack overflow. This is not a Noob question; it is very detailed and very specific.

Comment: @orokusaki: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), dude. That said, I've expanded the answer.

Comment: right... this isn’t an XY problem. I specified exactly the context of what I’m trying to do and the reason why, and in my case the exact problem is that having a decimal without its trailing zeros results in scientific notation, which makes the decimal less useful for later user output or debugging... that IS the problem. Please don’t confuse “I don’t know the answer” with “you asked the wrong question.”

Comment: @orokusaki: Seriously? No, it doesn't truncate the value. It does exactly what you asked for. Examples expanded to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 1):

according to the python 3.9 docs the below is how to do it - https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/decimal.html#decimal-faq

```
def remove_exponent(d):
    return d.quantize(Decimal(1)) if d == d.to_integral() else d.normalize()
```

Comment: Thanks! It is actually an "RTFM" statement but very useful indeed :)

Comment: Be aware that this will raise an exception for large integer inputs if the `quantize` result would require more digits than the configured precision. For example, under default settings, [passing `Decimal('1e60')` to this function will cause a `decimal.InvalidOperation` exception](https://ideone.com/BwxjcN). (The `Decimal('{:f}'.format(d.normalize()))` approach from the other answer will not raise this exception.)

Comment: (Both options will perform rounding on the `normalize` call, so neither option will preserve high-precision input.)

Answer (score 1):

Add `Decimal(0)` to your result.

```py
Decimal('50.000').normalize()
# Decimal('5E+1')


Decimal('50.000').normalize() + Decimal(0)
# Decimal('50')
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I've been trying to find an easy and non complicated one for the same issue and finally I found yours!