# PYTHON - How to iterate through a list of variables and change the value dependant on set conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variables

I have a list storing variables. These variables store float numbers. For part of the program I am making, if a value has .0 at the end, I need to remove it and if not, it can stay the same.

For example:
2.0 would become 2
3.5 would stay as 3.5

Now the issue is later on in the program I need to sort and round the same set of numbers up and down. The question would be too long if I included all of the reasoning for as to why this is.

The code I have currently is as follows:

```
AddRatio=0.35
SubRatio=0.2
MultiRatio=0.2
DiviRatio=0.2
MoneyRatio=0.25

num_add_qs=10*AddRatio
num_sub_qs=10*SubRatio
num_multi_qs=10*MultiRatio
num_divi_qs=10*DiviRatio
num_money_qs=10*MoneyRatio

NumQs = [num_add_qs, num_sub_qs, num_multi_qs, num_divi_qs, num_money_qs]

for i in range(0,len(NumQs)):
    if isinstance(NumQs[i], float) == True:
        NumQs[i]=str(NumQs[i])
        if NumQs[i][2]=="0":
            NumQs[i]=NumQs[i][0:1]
            NumQs[i]=int(NumQs[i])
        else:
            NumQs[i]=float(NumQs[i])
            i=i+1
```

If I

```
print(NumQs)
```

it returns

```
[3.5, 2, 2, 2, 2.5]
```

which are the results I want.

The issue is the actual value of the variable isn't changed.
If I:

```
print(num_add_qs, num_sub_qs, num_multi_qs, num_divi_qs, num_money_qs)
```

The result is:

```
3.5 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.5
```

The variables need to be stored as integers if whole integers and floats if not. I convert them to strings purely to remove the .0 if relevant.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/2440692/8150371

Comment: Which Python version you're using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5.2

Comment: The original variables will never change, what you are making here is a list of the original input and the list is an entity of its own. What you could do it , at the end add a line `[num_add_qs, num_sub_qs, num_multi_qs, num_divi_qs, num_money_qs] = NumQs` , that will do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things that I would improve with your current code:

- Don't use `isinstance`, instead use: `x == int(x)`.
- Never use lots of individual similar/linked variables, either store them all in a `list` (as you are) and forget about the variables or better **use a `dictionary`**.

---

So, taking the dictionary approach, here is what we get:

```
AddRatio=0.35
SubRatio=0.2
MultiRatio=0.2
DiviRatio=0.2
MoneyRatio=0.25

num_add_qs=10*AddRatio
num_sub_qs=10*SubRatio
num_multi_qs=10*MultiRatio
num_divi_qs=10*DiviRatio
num_money_qs=10*MoneyRatio

num_dict = {'add': 10*AddRatio, 'sub': 10*SubRatio, 'multi': 10*MultiRatio, \
            'divi': 10*DiviRatio, 'money': 10*MoneyRatio}

num_dict = {k: int(v) if v == int(v) else v for k, v in num_dict.items()}

# --> {'sub': 2, 'multi': 2, 'money': 2.5, 'add': 3.5, 'divi': 2}
```

---

So, as to answer your comment about how the dictionary comprehension works, here's my best explanation - through the interpreter as examples speak more than words:

```
>>> int(1.0) if 1.0 == int(1.0) else 1.0
1
>>> int(1.6) if 1.6 == int(1.6) else 1.6
1.6
>>> d = {'a': 1.0, 'b': 2.5, 'c': 3}
>>> d.items()
dict_items([('c', 3), ('a', 1.0), ('b', 2.5)])
>>> for k, v in d.items():
...     print("k: {}, v: {}".format(k, v))
... 
k: c, v: 3
k: a, v: 1.0
k: b, v: 2.5
>>> {i: i+2 for i in range(8)}
{0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 5, 4: 6, 5: 7, 6: 8, 7: 9}
>>> {k: int(v) if v == int(v) else v for k, v in d.items()}
{'c': 3, 'a': 1, 'b': 2.5}
```

Comment: That list comprehension is pretty neat. I'm learning how to do those and that's a fun one to"unpack". (..it's still a "list comprehension" even if it's used like a dictionary, yeah? Not called a "dictionary comprehension")

Comment: @BruceWayne Nope! It's called a dictionary comprehension :)

Comment: Could you briefly explain how num_dict = {k: int(v) if v == int(v) else v for k, v in num_dict.items()} works? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize the list with those variables, you are making a list with *copies of the values in those variables*. From that point forward, there exist two entirely separate sets of values: those assigned to your original variables such as `AddRatio` and `SubRatio`, and those in the list.

Basically, if you want to change the values of those variables, you need to mutate *those variables*. Mutating the list will only change the values contained in the list. If I write:

```
val1 = 1
val2 = 2
list = [val1, val2]
```

I get a list that looks like this:

```
[1, 2]
```

The list is now an entirely separate object, and it has its own `1` and `2`, if you will. Even if I change `val` like this:

```
val1 = 4
```

My list is still:

```
[1, 2]
```

And conversely, even if I change the list at index 0, `val1` will not change.

That said, this behavior only holds true for *primitive/immutable types* in Python, like ints or lambdas. If you start copying complex objects, you run into issues of "deep" vs "shallow" copies (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3975388/4243650)). The important thing to understand is that primitives are "pass by copy" whereas objects are "pass by reference". This difference is explained well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value).