# Convert Exponential values into float number on the fly in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, floating-point

I am trying to show decimal values instead of exponential values as it is required for end user.
You can see the code below,

```
currentValue1='1.56e-65'
print("%f" % float(currentValue1))
print(float(currentValue1))

output is:
0.000000
1.56e-65
```

I want to know, is there any way to show float value with all decimal values dynamically without formatting? something like following

`print("%.65f"%currentValue)`

Comment: What does "all decimal values" mean? Floats are stored in binary (with 53 bits for the significant digits), and once you convert the string representation to a float the original decimal form of the number is lost. And of course if you convert a float back to a decimal string the trailing digits will be different due to errors incurred in the conversion processes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting floats in Python without superfluous zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440692/formatting-floats-in-python-without-superfluous-zeros)

Comment: The whole point of formatting is that it allows you to control the float representation. Use formatting; that's exactly what it's for.

Comment: BTW, I'm skeptical that the end user _really_ wants to see `0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000156` in this case. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: @MarkDickinson yes, i am sure. But it is not about user front, but it is about UI front. In the JSON response, they want to see all decimal values. But anyway thanks for your responses.

Comment: All, thanks for your responses, there is no way i am really found to do this, so i made this conversion from UI side by accepting exponential values. Thanks for all your quick support