# Convert scientific notation to decimal with no trailing zeros

Tags: python, format, decimal, scientific-notation

I would like to have floats printed out

- in decimal notation
- with no trailing zeros

For instance:

```
1e-5    -> 0.00001
1.23e-4 -> 0.000123
1e-8    -> 0.00000001
```

---

Some things that don't work:

`str(x)` outputs scientific notation for small floats

`format(x, 'f')` and `"{:f}".format(x)` have fixed number of decimals, thus leave trailing zeroes

`('%f' % x).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')` rounds `1e-8` to `0`

```
from decimal import Decimal
(Decimal('0.00000001000').normalize())
```

uses scientific notation

`%0.10f` requires that I know ahead of time the precision of my floats

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting floats in Python without superfluous zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440692/formatting-floats-in-python-without-superfluous-zeros)

Comment: The answer to that question doesn't solve my problem. I edited my question in this regard.

Comment: Also from the question linekd, if you have decimals < 1e-6, you need to use a different format specifier: `%0.10f` could do the trick

Comment: But then I have to know ahead of time the maximal number of decimal places I will need

Comment: Well, there is a theoretical limit on how small your numbers can get, but I am sure there is pobably a practical limit how small a number you would expect and still want to output

Comment: An IEEE double has about log10(2^53)=15.95 decimal digits of precision. So just use `%.15f`.

Comment: You could construct a formatting string on the fly using the logarithm of the float.

Comment: @BennettBrown What would that look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you numbers are consistently like this, you could just modify the string:

```
number = "1.23155e-8" # as a string
lead, power = number.split("e-")
a, b = lead.split(".")
number = "0." + "0"*(int(power)-1) + a + b

print(number)
```

edit: fixed it.

Comment: This works great when my floats are small enough that I know str(number) will be formatted in a "1.2345e-6" style. But if I have `f=1e-1`, then I need an extra step to convert to scientific notation.

Answer (score 1):

Building on eugenhu's comment, rstrip('0') with 15 digits of precision seems to work for all your examples.

```
("%0.15f" % 1.e-5).rstrip('0')
Out[17]: '0.00001'

("%0.15f" % 1.e-8).rstrip('0')
Out[18]: '0.00000001'

("%0.15f" % 1.23e-4).rstrip('0')
Out[19]: '0.000123'
```