# Avoid decimal part in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal

Is there a way in Python to avoid the decimal part of number result when it is zero?

When `a = 12` and `b = 2` I want:

```
print(a/b)
```

to print:

```
6   # not 6.0
```

and if `a = 13` and `b = 2`

```
6.5 # not 6
```

in a generic way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting floats in Python without superfluous zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440692/formatting-floats-in-python-without-superfluous-zeros)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use floor division if `b` divides `a` without remainder and normal division else:

```
data = [ (12,2),(13,2)]

for a,b in data:
    print(f"{a} / {b} = ",  a // b if (a//b == a/b) else a / b)
```

Output:

```
12 / 2 = 6
13 / 2 = 6.5
```

This is a ternary coditional statement (more: [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)) and it evaluates `a//b == a/b`.

`a//b` is floordiv and `a/b` is normal div, they are only ever equal if `b` divides `a` without remainder (more: [What is the difference between '/' and '//' when used for division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the int()/ round() methods. All one would have to do is

```
print(int(a/b))
```

Comment: but i dont want to check for every result if it has decimals or if it doesnt have(.0).