# How to convert Json to pandas by condition

Tags: pandas

I have the following jason:

```
{'ADA': {'free': '0.00000000', 'locked': '1.32580000'},
 'ADX': {'free': '15.0000000', 'locked': '0.00000000'},
 'AE': {'free': '0.23000000', 'locked': '1.253000000'},
 'ZRX': {'free': '0.00000000', 'locked': '0.00000000'}}
```

I am trying to convert the above Jason to pandas but only the lines which has amount <> 0 in "free" or in "locked" + with no "0" when not needed so ZRX regarding the above example will not be shown and 1.2530000 will be only 1.253

My desired pandas will be:

```
    free   locked
ADA 0      1.3258
ADX 15     0
AE  0.23   1.253
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: Jason? Do you mean JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) first, then convertto floats and filter by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), last for strings without trailing `0` use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2440708/2901002):

```
d =  {'ADA': {'free': '0.00000000', 'locked': '1.32580000'},
 'ADX': {'free': '15.0000000', 'locked': '0.00000000'},
 'AE': {'free': '0.23000000', 'locked': '1.253000000'},
 'ZRX': {'free': '0.00000000', 'locked': '0.00000000'}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index')

df = df.astype(float)

df = df[df['free'].ne(0) | df['locked'].ne(0)].applymap('{0:g}'.format)
#if need remove 0 from all rows
#df = df[df.ne(0).any(axis=1)].applymap('{0:g}'.format)
print (df)
     free  locked
ADA     0  1.3258
ADX    15       0
AE   0.23   1.253
```

Comment: why when trying to do free+locked i get only free? even after i rechange the df to float?

Comment: @Giladbi -  Not sure if understand, can you explain more? How you get values? If check `print (df.dtypes)` there are not both float columns?

Comment: it's an object. I change it to "df = df.astype(float)" and still getting a+b =a or b+a =b

Comment: @Giladbi - Are data confidental?

Comment: I added "balance['Total Position'] = (balance['locked']) + (balance['free'])" and the results are: free locked Total Position
AAA   2.99831      0       02.99831

Comment: Data columns (total 3 columns):
free              7 non-null object
locked            7 non-null object
Total Position    7 non-null object
dtypes: object(3)

Comment: @Giladbi - So i think problem is with `applymap('{0:g}'.format)` - it convert floats to strings. So need `df = df.astype(float)` and then `df['Total Position'] = (df['locked']) + (df['free'])` and last `df = df[df['free'].ne(0) | df['locked'].ne(0)].applymap('{0:g}'.format)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
json = {'ADA': {'free': '0.00000000', 'locked': '1.32580000'},
 'ADX': {'free': '15.0000000', 'locked': '0.00000000'},
 'AE': {'free': '0.23000000', 'locked': '1.253000000'},
 'ZRX': {'free': '0.00000000', 'locked': '0.00000000'}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json).astype(float).transpose()
df = df.applymap(lambda s: str(s).rstrip('0').rstrip('.') if '.' in str(s) else s)
df = df[~((df['free']=='0') & (df['locked']=='0'))]   # This is to drop row containing all zeros
print(df)



     free  locked
ADA     0  1.3258
ADX    15       0
AE   0.23   1.253
```