# Removing ".00" from Decimal format numbers to make them whole numbers keeping other decimal numbers intact

Tags: python-3.x

I have a column that has Amount rounded to 2 decimal places. So there are two types of enteries, one of the form 359.00 and others 359.78. I want to remove .00 from the first form of enteries to make it interger(359) keeping the decimal format of other number intact.

Comment: Hello! Why column? Usually you have a list. Are you working with a dataframe? (pandas maybe)? If so, please specifiy, may be relevant.

Comment: hi. yes its a pandas dataframe with one column as Amount.

Answer (score 0):

#### Data are floating numbers

A column don't have mixed types. Assuming your data are stored as floating numbers (`dtype: float64`), they will remain floats. What you can do is to use a custom format so that they are shown on the screen as you wish, but internally they remains floats. For example:

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame.from_records([(1,), (3.34,), (2.49,), (5,), (7,)], columns=['Amount'])
pd.options.display.float_format = lambda x : "{:2.2f}".format(x).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
print(dfa)
```

This prints:

```
   Amount  
0       1  
1    3.34  
2    2.49  
3       5  
4       7
```

#### Data are strings

If instead your data are just strings representing numbers (`dtype: object`) you can use [pandas.applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap) to actually edit the strings according to a format style.

```
dfb = pd.DataFrame.from_records([("1.00",), ("3.34",), ("2.49",), ("5.00",), ("7.00",)], columns=['Amount'])
dfbb = dfb.applymap(lambda x : str(x).rstrip('0').rstrip('.'))
print(dfbb)
```

This prints (again):

```
  Amount
0      1
1   3.34
2   2.49
3      5
4      7
```

#### Data are floating numbers but you want strings

In this case you can combine the two methods:

```
dfc = dfa.applymap(lambda x : "{:2.2f}".format(x).rstrip('0').rstrip('.'))
print(dfc)
```

Starting from a dataframe with floating numbers, you end with a dataframe of formatted strings. It prints the same, no need to touch pandas format settings.

Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440692/formatting-floats-in-python-without-superfluous-zeros) for the basic idea.