# How to modify the real value with a multiply operation

Tags: python, rounding, floating-accuracy

A simple question :

**1)** In Python using numpy, how to get without parisitic decimals the follwing result (true value 0.6968) ? :

```
>>> 0.67*(1.04)
0.6968000000000001
```

If I convert to string, I can find the right value :

```
>>> str(0.67*(1.04))
'0.6968'
```

**2)** By the way, how to control the rounding to systematically get the real value ? I saw that epsilon machine with Python (and/or Numpy) **was around 2e-16**.

So, I conclude that taking 16 decimals is too small and implies random values after 16th decimal or more precisely below 2e-16.

I don't want to troll but Matlab (I like also Python) doesn't produce this kind of error.

Comment: i didn't get ur second question. explain it more pls.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting floats in Python without trailing zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440692/formatting-floats-in-python-without-trailing-zeros)

Comment: What has this to do with "parasitic decimals"?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco . I am talking about the `1` into Python result, i.e `0.6968000000000001`

Comment: @kaya This is weird, whay does Matlab enable it and not python ? What's the difference between both from an implementation point of view ? I know we can't compare since sources of Matlab are private, so it's going to be pretty difficult to compare... Intel Pythom seems to have the same bug.

Comment: You're looking at a string representation in decimal, not the actual number which is stored as a double-precision IEEE 754 floating point number. Please see the link I posted.

Comment: @kaya3 . Ok so no way to get directly in Python terminal or in code : `0.67*1.04 = 0.6968` ? However, I like open sources languages but sometimes, proprietary does better... it's frustrating ...

Comment: This is explained in the link which I posted.

Comment: @youpilat13 I am just confused why you specifically mention "parisitic decimals", from reading https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitic_number it seems they have no relation to your question

Comment: @HymnsForDisco . I wanted just to mean  decimals that shouldn't exist in the result given par Python. I take for example the same operation but with Matlab, with which the result is printed right.

Comment: @youpilat13 To hopefully clear some of your confusion: In computing, generally there is no such thing as a pure "number" as we have in mathematics, but rather representations of numbers within limited datatypes.  No datatype is capable of representing *all* numbers. In a sense, you could say that the result Python gives is incorrect, because your code is incorrect.  Neither `0.67`, `1.04` or `0.6968` can be represented exactly by a float, its as if they're impossible numbers.  You could try using the built-in decimal module, then your problem is solved until you need a `1/3`, `1/6`, `1/7`...

Comment: Matlab also uses floating point types internally and has the same fundamental problems. The only difference is that it may make different formatting choices when printing numeric values so that you don't see the blemishes, but they are still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `%g` for that.

```
x = 0.67*(1.04)
x = '%g'%(x)
print("x:",x)
```

your question is duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440692/formatting-floats-in-python-without-trailing-zeros).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Is there an automatic (or implicit) way to apply this converting for all floats in my code, I mean without explicitly having to do a `x = '%g'%(x)` for each of all variables ?? It would be nice.

Comment: @youpilat13 It would be much more appropriate to just use [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) for all your numeric values