# How to turn float into int only if the float has an integer value?

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a float which has an integer value into a int, so it doesn't look like e.g 5.0.

```
#Quadratic calculator
import math

def is_int(x):
    x = float(x)
    if x.is_integer():
        a = int(x)
        return a
    else:
        pass

print("Quadratic Equation: ax^2 + bx + c = 0" )
a = float(input("a: "))
b = float(input("b: "))
c = float(input("c: "))
if a.is_integer():
    a = int(a)
else:
    pass
is_int(b)

print(str(a)+"x + "+str(b)+"x + "+ str(c)+ " = 0")

result=[]
result.append(-b+((b**2)-(4*a*c)**0.5)/(2*a))
result.append(-b-((b**2)-(4*a*c)**0.5)/(2*a))
print("x: " + str(result[0]) + " or " + "x: " + str(result[1]))
```

The result is:

```
Quadratic Equation: ax^2 + bx + c = 0
a: 2
b: 5
c: 1
2x + 5.0x + 1.0 = 0
x: 0.5428932188134521 or x: -10.542893218813452
```

Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: You have the `is_int` function that does just that (well, it's close to what you want) - why are you not using it?

Comment: By the way, `else: pass` is unnecessary.

Comment: There's probably a number of other ways of doing it — what exactly is your concern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could work a bit on yout `is_int` function:

```
def is_int(x):
    x = float(x)
    if x.is_integer():
        return int(x)
     return x
```

and then just use in your code:

```
a = is_int(a)
b = isint(b)
c = is_int(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First, simplify your `is_int` method, and make it return a value and `is_integer()` is false

   ```
   def is_int(x):
       x = float(x)
       if x.is_integer():
           return int(x)
       return x
   ```
2. use  it directly at the input place

   ```
   a = is_int(input("a: "))
   b = is_int(input("b: "))
   c = is_int(input("c: "))
   ```

> Out
>
> ```
> Quadratic Equation: ax^2 + bx + c = 0
> a: 2.5
> b: 5
> c: 1.4
> 2.5x + 5x + 1.4 = 0
> x: -0.748331477354788 or x: -9.251668522645211
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Look duplicate question [Formatting floats without trailing zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2440708/2101808).

Use `:g` format for string

```
print('{a:g}x2 + {b:g}x + {c:g} = 0'.format(a=a,b=b,c=c))
```

Out

```
>>> a=5.0
>>> b=3.0
>>> c=4.0
>>> print('{a:g}x² + {b:g}x + {c:g} = 0'.format(a=a,b=b,c=c))
5x² + 3x + 4 = 0
>>>
```

Comment: Yes, this method is better than  function and much simpler, thank u. But how did u get that x squared output?

Comment: Just unicode char. I using hotkey, but you also can google common characters `Unicode Character 'SUPERSCRIPT TWO'

`

Answer (score 0):

I would simply your `is_int` function into a one line like this:

```py
def is_int(x):
    return int(x) if float(x).is_integer() else float(x)
```

Comment: @MLGGuardian It's very simple, it will return the `int` version of `x` if it is an `int` if not it will return the `float` version. You can try it.