# How to get just "3" and not "3.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vector

```
import numpy as np

def median(x):
    y = np.median(x).
    return y
```

My output is "3.0" when it is supposed to be "3" the other answer is right which is "3.5"

Comment: Here's a couple of ideas: 1) Convert the median value to [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) before printing. 2) Use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) to change how the value is displayed.

Comment: @0x5453. That won't help for the case that's correctly reporting 3.5

Comment: That is expected as the documentation for [np.median](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.median.html) indicates that: *If the input contains integers or floats smaller than float64, then the output data-type is `np.float64`. Otherwise, the data-type of the output is the same as that of the input. If out is specified, that array is returned instead.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting floats without trailing zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440692/formatting-floats-without-trailing-zeros)

Answer (score 2):

This result is due to the fact that the `np.median()` function returns a float, not an integer. If you want the result to return an integer if it's not a decimal value, then you can use the code below:

```
import numpy as np

def median(x):
    y = np.median(x)
    return int(y) if y%1==0 else y
```

If we run `print(median([4,3,1,5,2]), median([4,3,1,5,2,6]))`, the output will be: 3 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

def median(x):
    y = np.median(x)
    if y % 1 == 0:
        y = np.int16(y)
    return y

print(median([4,3,1,5,2]), median([4,3,1,5,2,6]))
```