# Convert string to float without leading and trailing zeros

Tags: python

I recieve data in string format:

```
input1 = ",1"
input2 = "1,"
```

I need to convert it into float and validate it in my tests.
I expect this kind of convertion:

```
",1" -> 0.1
"1," -> 1.0
```

Is it possible without using regular expressions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting floats without trailing zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440692/formatting-floats-without-trailing-zeros)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6633912/13843268) for details (question title is otherwise misleading).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can substitute the `,` with `.` using `replace()` and then convert to `float`

```
float(input1.replace(',','.'))
```

Comment: Oh I didn't expect float(".1") to be translated to 0.1. I'll have to read the documentation more carefully.