# 2 Different Data Frames + Percentage Calculation + Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, percentage, accumulate

there are similar questions existing, however cant find the right answer. Most of them require a common nominator which I don't have.

I want to have two outcomes from two data frames.

One is to get the percentage for each row in df2 from the total (df1). And another view of accumulated percentage.

```
df1
a
1875


df2
b   c
aaa 125
bbb 250
ccc 500
ddd 1000


Required outcome. 

b   c   Outcome 1   Outcome 2
aaa 125     6.67%       100.00%
bbb 250    13.33%        93.33%
ccc 500    26.67%        80.00%
ddd 1000   53.33%        53.33%
```

I have tried df1.eq(df2.values).mean() and couple of the merge functions. But again, don't have a common nominator.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#get scalar from first DataFrame
a = df1.loc[0, 'a']

#divide by scalar and multiple by 100
df['Outcome 1'] = df['c'].div(a).mul(100)
#create cumulative sum in swapped order of rows
df['Outcome 2'] = df['Outcome 1'].iloc[::-1].cumsum()
print (df)
     b     c  Outcome 1   Outcome 2
0  aaa   125   6.666667  100.000000
1  bbb   250  13.333333   93.333333
2  ccc   500  26.666667   80.000000
3  ddd  1000  53.333333   53.333333
```

Comment: perfect thanks. I am able to add % to it by doing .round(0).map("{:}%".format). However, I am still getting 100.0%. How can I get rid the .0?

Comment: @Rav86 - Use `.map("{:g}%".format)`, [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2440708/2901002)