# python how to handle float data like this？

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point

There are some data type is float, for example

> 24.0, 34.0, 35.6, 33.2, 44.0

I want

> 24.0, 34.0, 44.0

change into

> 24,34,44.

`35.6` and `33.2` do not change.

how could I do that?

Comment: You can also refer to [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/385325/5066845).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me put that data types into a list,

```
 list_num = [24.0, 34.0, 35.6, 33.2, 44.0]
 newList=[int(i) if int(i)== i else i for i in list_num]
 print newList
```

Comment: if you were looking for this please make this the best answer , Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `44.0 == 44 #True` you can do the following:

```
li = [24.0, 34.0, 35.6, 33.2, 44.0]
print map(lambda x: int(x) if int(x) == x else x, li)
>> [24, 34, 35.6, 33.2, 44]
```

Answer (score 1):

using string formatting:

```
>>> l = [24.0, 34.0, 35.6, 33.2, 44.0]
>>> ['{0:g}'.format(x) for x in l]
['24', '34', '35.6', '33.2', '44']
```