# Can't .rstrip('.0') after a function PYTHON

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

```
def competitiveEating(t, width, precision):
    return str(round(t, precision)).center(width).rstrip('.0')
```

so I want to remove trailing .0s from whole numbers given through my input t thats being rounded to the precision number, when I do r.strip after .center nothing happens, I don't know much so I'm not sure if you can even put a .function after another .function (the rstrip after center). I was reading about      '{0:g}'.format(float(21)) here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385325/dropping-trailing-0-from-floats) (the solved question doesn't work in this situation). I honestly don't even know how to add or use the {0:g}'.format(float(21)) part..

Comment: probably python. tag with programming language please

Comment: rstrip first, then call center, else a short number will be space padded on left and right sides, and rstrip('.0') won't find any '.'s or '0's to strip, just the trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do that:

```python
def competitiveEating(t, width, precision):
    text = str(round(t, precision))
    if text.endswith('.0'):
        text = text[:-2]
    return text.center(width)
```

Comment: Thanks but r.strip('.0') removes all instances of '.' and '0'

Comment: You're right. I believe I have a corrected version now.

Comment: I think the OP wants to strip all 0's after a decimal, so "1.000" should become "1", and this will fail since it does not end with '.0'.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire The input `t` is a number, not a string, as shown by it being put through `round`, which doesn't take strings. `str(1.000)` is `"1.0"`, so it doesn't have the problem you mention.

Answer (score 0):

```
def competitiveEating(t, width, precision):
return ("{:."+str(precision)+"f}").format(t).center(width)
```

The way you are rounding up won't work for things like `precision = 0`, and if it is something like `1000.00`, you will end up with `1`.

**And if you don't care about this, you could do it like this:**

```
def competitiveEating(t, width, precision):
    return str(round(t, precision)).rstrip('.0').center(width)
```