# how to remove zeros after decimal from string remove all zero after dot

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame with a object column lets say col1, which has values likes:
1.00,
1,
0.50,
1.54

I want to have the output like the below:
1,
1,
0.5,
1.54
basically, remove zeros after decimal values if it does not have any digit after zero. Please note that i need answer for dataframe. pd.set_option and round don't work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove decimal points in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084812/how-to-remove-decimal-points-in-pandas)

Comment: Are you certain you have strings? And if you do. Why would you want to store numbers as strings?

Comment: 1) it is not duplicate. i checked  the given link.

Comment: 2) i need to have blank value in case of null values so keep it string.

Comment: Ok thanks for answers. In the case of 2) though: A null value in number is in the dataframe a np.nan value (displayed as NaN). This means: Not a Number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want convert integers and floats numbers to strings with no trailing `0` use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12080042) with `map` or `apply`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1.00, 1, 0.5, 1.50]})

df['new'] = df['col1'].map('{0:g}'.format)
#alternative solution
#df['new'] = df['col1'].apply('{0:g}'.format)
print (df)
   col1  new
0   1.0    1
1   1.0    1
2   0.5  0.5
3   1.5  1.5

print (df['new'].apply(type))
0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'str'>
2    <class 'str'>
3    <class 'str'>
Name: new, dtype: object
```

Comment: I am getting the below error  message: ValueError: Unknown format code 'g' for object of type 'str'

Comment: jezrael,your above example work if the 'col1' is float. otherwise it through error message. my issue is with string (object) data type

Comment: @Alexsander - How working `df['new'] = df['col1'].astype(float).map('{0:g}'.format)` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work:

```
if val.is_integer() == True :
    val = int(val)
elif val.is_float() == True :
    val = Decimal(val).normalize()
```

Assuming that `val` is a `float` value inside the dataframe's column. You simply cast the value to be integer.
For float value instead you cut extra zeros.

Answer (score 0):

A quick-and-dirty solution is to use `"%g" % value`, which will convert floats `1.5` to `1.5` but `1.0` to `1` and so on. The negative side-effect is that large numbers will be represented in scientific notation like `4.44e+07`.

Comment: CSI,thank you for the quick reply. since i am new to python. could you give me some example using dataframe, please? I never used "%g" % value before.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37084889/10484131), I think you'd like to change the display precision of pandas like so:

```
pd.set_option('precision', 0)
```

Comment: Good find, but this is a duplicate answer, not a separate.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I'm new to Stackoverflow. Is linking to a previous answer and citing parts of its content bad? Sorry but I couldn't find authoritative sources that define a duplicate answer.

Comment: No worries, I don't know if you have that option yet but there is a close question button at top where you can click towards --> duplicate answer.

Comment: Thanks again. Seems like I'm still missing privileges. Also I just realized that my answer is wrong I think, because the question was referring to strings. Should I delete it? Or keep it for reference?

Answer (score 0):

How about the `str.rstrip` method. Like so (assuming your strings are in a list):

```
a = ["1.00", "1" ,"0.50", "1.50"]

b = [e.rstrip('.0') for e in a]

>>> ['1', '1', '0.5', '1.5']
```

Comment: No, because it change all integers ended with `0` - `a = ["1.00", "100" ,"0.50", "1.50"]` create `['1', '1', '0.5', '1.5']`