# Color 1 word in a text string in Pandas Dataframe and corresponding values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using jupyter notebook to return this dataframe. I am trying to color the word "Bullish" green and "Bearish" red. Also if it is bullish the Buy/Sell Trade price should be green and Bearish the Buy/Sell price should be Red. Thanks for your help!

Sample file here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WWdFlXIqQCM6LyeWZglPzqUwhCy3blTD?usp=sharing

[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3VXZ.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta 

df_rr = pd.read_csv("W:\mac\dev\py\RR.csv", parse_dates=["DATE"], index_col="DATE")
df_rr.loc["2021-03-10"]
```

---

**EDIT 1**

The code works but it drops my date column. DO you know what happened to it? Also when I use this code, I get the following error. I want to be able to return 1 date of data so that is why I use: df_rr.loc["2021-03-10"]

I get AttributeError: 'Styler' ojbect has no attribute 'loc'

is there a better way to limit by one date?

---

**EDIT 2**

3/12/2021
Thanks for your edit. One final thing, can you help make the text in the INDEX column for Bullish and Bearish colored as well. Really appreciate you.

**FOLLOW UP** - This works great but can I only have the words BULLISH and BEARISH colored instead of the full text string? Thanks!

---

**EDIT 3**

It looks the new code adds zeros to my values. How do you chop trailing zeros in the price columns? Thanks!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yH0s.png)

**EDIT 4 - 4/2/2021**

### [Here is the original data + code to load the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWGjL.png)

[Here is the view after I add in your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMTNi.png)

3 questions:

1. Why are there 0's being added to my data (in BUY TRADE & SELL TRADE Columns)?
2. Is it possible to just have the Words BULLISH be GREEN, BEARISH BE RED and NEUTRAL be GRAY?
3. DATE column gets changed to have time, can we remove the time?

Thanks as always!

Comment: You must usr `r"..."` when your string include backslashes.

Comment: Look at [style](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html).

Comment: The code drop date column. By code you mean mine one. Instead of `df.reset_index(drop=True)` use ` df.reset_index()` that drop thing is removing the date index

Comment: You want to colour the whole text of index or only those words? If you mean  whole index row then I will update my answer. will require little modification.

Comment: Include traceback or error in the post. but if the query is link to the answer(someone) then comment on it.

Comment: this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52889398/6660373

Comment: BTW did you see my edit1 answer You can see that I ain't getting any tarilling zero. But if you do get try to use map as shown in the link.

Comment: I changed the code in Edit 1 - and it now errs returning: TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable first errors on this line of code:   if 'BULLISH' in x['INDEX']:

Comment: show me the screenshot. musdatt be related to axis. you are taking value rowise that's why. Are you sure you have the data after using loc. You are not getting empty data?

Comment: Are you still stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can colour using `style`

```
def cts(x):
    c1 = 'color: red'
    c2 = 'color: green'
    c3 = 'color: black'
    if 'BULLISH' in x['INDEX']:
        return c3,c1,c1
    elif 'BEARISH' in x['INDEX']:
        return c3,c2,c2
    else:
        return c3,c3,c3

df = df.reset_index(drop=True).style.apply(cts,subset=['INDEX', 'BUY TRADE', 'SELL TRADE'], axis=1)
```

---

**df:**

[image]

### EDIT:

```
df.loc['2020-12-07'].reset_index().style.apply(cts,subset=['INDEX', 'BUY TRADE', 'SELL TRADE'], axis=1)
```

[image]

### EDIT2:

If you want to colour `INDEX` also do: (Initially I was showing black but for those you can change the color to red/green based on the condition)

```
if 'BULLISH' in x['INDEX']:
    return c1,c1,c1
elif 'BEARISH' in x['INDEX']:
    return c2,c2,c2
else:
    return c3,c3,c3
```

Comment: @mac why you need to do `.loc` ?? Edit your post with screenshot where you stuck. Don;r write it in the comment difficult for me to interpret.